# How to save photos sent in Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, photos

My friends and I often share pictures via Facebook and Facebook Messenger app.

I cannot save the photos to my gallery.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touch the image and it will be viewed bigger.

Then hold the Menu button.

A menu will come up.

Go for `Settings - Save Image` to save the image and it will be saved to your photo album.

Comment: Thank you. But I touch the image. It is viewed bigger. Then I open menu as you suggest, but all I get is `Settings | Help | Report Bug`. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of android are you running?

Comment: My fone is Google Galaxy Nexus - the version is Android 4.2.1 Jelly Bean

Answer (score 1):

You can download chat shared photos on android. I saw a quick tip [Here](http://infoinspired.com/how-to-guides/how-to-download-photos-sent-in-facebook-chat-on-android/).

Comment: Can you summarize the contents of the site rather than just hyper linking it?

Comment: The tip you saw is really not clear indeed :(

Answer (score 1):

Open Facebook on your browser instead of running the Facebook. App. Tap on any photo to open the context menu with download option.

Answer (score 0):

- Touch and long press the image on the chat and on the context menu you will be able to see `Save` option.
- Hit the `Save` option to download the image and go to your `Gallery` app where you can find the downloaded image.